# Prove that $T$ is invertible if and only if $p=m$ and $B$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Assume $p,n,m$ are positive integers, and $T: \mathbb M_{m \times n}(\mathbb F) \to \mathbb M_{p \times n}(\mathbb F)$ is a linear transformation such that $\forall A \in \mathbb M_{m \times n}(\mathbb F):A \mapsto BA$,where $B$ is a fixed $p \times m$ matrix.Prove that $T$ is invertible if and only if $p=m$ and $B$ is invertible.

---

If $T$ is invertible then it takes the a basis of  $\mathbb M_{m \times n}(\mathbb F)$ to a basis of  $\mathbb M_{p \times n}(\mathbb F)$,from here we have that $mn=pn \implies m=p$,but I don't know how to show that $B$ is invertible.

For the other direction the linear transformation $G:\mathbb M_{p \times n}(\mathbb F) \to \mathbb M_{m \times n}(\mathbb F)$ with $A \mapsto B^{-1}A$ can be seen as the inverse of $T$.

Comment: Hint: If $T$ is invertible there is a preimage of the identity matrix.

Comment: If $T$ is invertible it is surjective, so there is some $A$ with $T(A)=I$.

Comment: Nevermind, this approach only makes sense in the case $m=n$ (otherwise there is not an identity matrix), I will try to modify my argument

Answer (score 1):

Assume $T$ is invertible and $\ker B\ne0$. Since $n>0$ there is a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with $0\ne\operatorname{im}A\subseteq\ker B$. But then $T(A)=BA=0$, so by the injectivity of $T$ we get $A=0$ which contradicts $\operatorname{im}A\ne0$.
Therefore $\ker B=0$ and since $B$ is a square-matrix this implies that $B$ is invertible.

Comment: $\ker B=\{x\in F^n\mid Bx=0\}$ and $\operatorname{im}A=\{Ax\mid x\in F^n\}$